# Как создать сайт со списком решений?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Хочу создать сайт,где будут публиковаться решения математических задач. По сути, решебник для одной книги. Задач в ней много.

Допустим, есть решения 100 задач. Для каждого из них создавать отдельную HTML-страницу не лучшее решение.

Как решить проблему?
Обязательна ли база данных для этого?

Comment: почему не хорошее решение? в чем заключается проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, формируйте заголовок так, чтобы по нему была понятна тема

Comment: Генераторы статических сайтов к вашим услугам

Answer (score 6):

> Для каждого из них создавать отдельную HTML-страницу не лучшее решение.

Да **норма-а-ально**. Другой вопрос, что **не стоит это делать вручную**, конечно же.

Возьмите любой **генератор статических сайтов**, сделайте в нём **шаблон** и делайте странички, ссылающиеся на этот шаблон.

После этого запускаете генератор, и *вуаля*: отдельные красивые и полные HTML-странички на каждую задачу. Поменяли шаблон? Запустите генератор снова, и все страницы обновятся.

Лично я пользуюсь [**Jekyll** (там же документация)](http://jekyllrb.com/). Он использует данные в шапке страницы на языке [YAML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), чтобы понять, какой применять шаблон (и ряда других вещей, которые вам на начальном этапе не потребуются), а также [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki) для, собственно, шаблонов.

Писать отдельные странички можно на HTML, но гораздо удобнее на одном из языков разметки, предназначенных для редактирования **контента**: рекомендуется [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), который неплохо выглядит и в необработанном виде (к слову, этот ответ написан на нём же).

Результатом работы Jekyll является пачка HTML-страниц, которые вы можете загрузить куда хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри в сторону wordpress, joomla, drupal.
Если есть какие либо знания в программировании, то лучше Jekyll + GitHub Page + Mathjax.
Mathjax кажется можно использовать и с wordpress, joomla, drupal.